# Fortifying an already fortified city (or placing a caravan in a city with a caravan)

Tags: civilization-board-game

In Civilization *Fame and Fortune* expansion, a player may disband his army/scout figure in one of his cities. Disbanding a army figure is called *fortification*, and this gives an additional one-time-use +2 combat bonus. Discarding a scout is called *sending a caravan*, and it gives a one-time-use +2 production to the city.

Is it a legal move to discard scout/army figures voluntarily and without benefits to an already fortified/'caravanicated' city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This was covered by the [FAQ, v2.0](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf):

> **Q:** Can a player disband an army figure in a city that already contains a fortification marker, or a scout in a city that already contains a caravan marker?
>
> **A:** Yes. However, the player does not add an additional fortification or caravan marker, or gain an additional bonus.